# A matrix $M$ is similar to [$T$]$_B$ $\iff$ there exists a basis $B'$ such that $M =$ [$T$]$_{B'}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space V with basis $B$. Then a matrix $M$ is similar to [$T$]$_B$ $\iff$ there exists a basis $B'$ such that $M =$ [$T$]$_{B'}$ .

I am having difficulty with the forward direction. Suppose that $M$ is similar to 
 [$T$]$_B$. Then there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that 
$M=P^{-1}$[$T$]$_BP$.

I have no idea how to then show that there must exist a $B'$ such that $M =$ [$T$]$_{B'}$ . Hints or solutions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there exists an invertible $P$ such that $M = P^{-1} [T]_B P$. Let $B=\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$. Then the columns of $[T]_B$ denote the images of $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ in this basis. Consider the columns of $P^{-1}$ as your new basis $B'$. For example if $n=2$ and $P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, then we consider $B' = \{b_1,b_1+b_2\}$. We denote the elements of the new basis as $b'_i$, so in this example, $b'_1=b_1$ and $b'_2 = b_1+b_2$. In particular, if some vector $v$ is written in the $B'$ basis as $[v]_{B'}$, then $[v]_{B} = P[v]_{B'}$.

Then, $M[b'_i]_{B'} = P^{-1}[T]_B P [b'_i]_{B'} = P^{-1}[T]_B [b'_i]_B = P^{-1} [Tb'_i]_B = [Tb'_i]_{B'}$.

Comment: Does it follow necessarily that P will always be equal to $[I]^{B'}_{B}$

Comment: @JamesDickens I am not certain what that notation means, but yes $P$ is essentially a change of basis between $B$ and $B'$.